# Base64 Image Comparison

Tags: python, c++, image, base64

Let say I have two Images A and B, same size, same number of channels and same format (for example both RGB images of size 25x25 in PNG).

I want to compare these two images and give a score on how much these two images are different based on **sum of the differences on each pixel**. However, these images are encoded in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) format (like images in HTML pages).

My question is whether summing up the differences of each character in Base64 format necessarily gives an estimation on how A and B are different or similar?

Comment: No, it doesn't. A single bit difference in the LSB of a few pixels could result in totally different files.

Comment: What kind of similarity measure are you trying to achieve? For example, if one image is a shifted version of the other, should that be detectable?

Comment: @MarkSnyder Only sum on pixel to pixel comparison. If one is shifted, they are not necessarily similar. Only comparing each pixel to the other one in same index.

Comment: @MarkSetchell to be clear the bigger difference will come from the compression applied by PNG, not the encoding from base64.

Comment: @MarkRansom Exactly. If the first scanline of one image is repetitive but not in the other image, it could get filtered differently and come out as a different number of bytes and the rest of the image might be identical but the alignment would be out of kilter.

Comment: Why is base 64 relevant? A number is a number regardless of base. It's the same number whether it's expressed in base 2, base 10, base 64 or *whatever* base.. same number.

Comment: @JesperJuhl This is a bit different. In Base64 encoding, each character represents a `6-bit` value. So they break a file of bytes into `6-bit` by `6-bit` and put a character for each value.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I wrote a test and now I agree, it doesn't.

Comment: What is wrong with decoding them, first?

Comment: @TheFailurebyDesign Decreasing number of steps and increasing performance

Comment: It won’t work. Base64 enc/dec is very fast. If written correctly, the compiler will generate vectorized code. See the boost implementation - you can easily copy it if you do not want to include the library.

Comment: You problem statement is not clear. What do you mean PNG then encoded in base64? Or compare PNG encoding vs base64 encoding of a raw pixelmap? PNG but with loss or not? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a test in Python to generate three random images `img1, img2, img3`. Then compare them first pixel by pixel and then compare their Base64 version. I tried to see if `img1` is more similar to `img2` or `img3` and then test if both comparisons are correlated.

The answer is **No**. They are not correlated. In my test, they were not correlated for 488 times out of 1000 tests.

```py
import numpy as np
import base64

# Generates an image with random values
def generate_image():
    img = np.random.random((10,10,3)) * 255
    return np.uint8(img)

# First comparison method based on pixel to pixel comparison
def compare_numpy(img1, img2):
    return np.sum( np.abs( img1 - img2 ) )

# Second comparison method based on comparing Base64 versions
def compare_base64(img1, img2):
    b1 = list(base64.b64encode(img1))
    b2 = list(base64.b64encode(img2))
    return sum( abs(b1[i] - b2[i]) for i in range(len(b1)))

# Test if both methods says if img1 is closer to img2 or img3
def correlation_test():
    img1 = generate_image()
    img2 = generate_image()
    img3 = generate_image()

    # img1 is closer to img2 or img3

    # Testing pixel to pixel comparison
    cmp12 = compare_numpy(img1, img2)
    cmp13 = compare_numpy(img1, img3)
    if cmp12 < cmp13:
        result1 = 2
    else:
        result1 = 3

    # Testing Base64 comparison
    cmp12 = compare_base64(img1, img2)
    cmp13 = compare_base64(img1, img3)
    if cmp12 < cmp13:
        result2 = 2
    else:
        result2 = 3

    return result1 == result2

true_cnt = 0
false_cnt = 0

# Running the test 1000 times
for i in range(1000):
    if correlation_test():
        true_cnt += 1
    else:
        false_cnt += 1

print(f"They are correlated {true_cnt} times")
print(f"They are not correlated {false_cnt} times")

# They are correlated 512 times
# They are not correlated 488 times
```